# How create Custom Indoor Map with directions for iPhone?

Tags: ios, iphone, google-maps, mapkit, maptiler

I am developing an application for exhibition. I am new to the map concept (tile map)in iOS.  In this app I have to show a map of all the exhibition stall(booth). I've searched about tiled map but unable to find proper example and documentation. Can anyone help with the example?

Answer (score 0):

You can read in this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/map#indoor_maps) that indoor floor plans are integrated into the default map tiles for the 'normal' map type (`kGMSTypeNormal`), and are automatically enabled when the user zooms in, and fade away when the map is zoomed out. You can use the [GMSIndoorDisplay Class](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/interface_g_m_s_indoor_display) to observe or control the display of indoor level data. Here's a [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tcJhtk0Xc_M) which might help.